# Find number of rows for each hour where datetime columns match certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

**RDBMS**: MySQL

The time column(s) datatype is of **datetime**

For every hour of the 24 hour day I need to retrieve the number of rows in which their **start_time** matches the hour OR the **end_time** is great than or equal to the hour.

Below is the current query I have which returns the data I need but only based off of one hour. I can loop through and do 24 separate queries for each hour of the day but I would love to have this in one query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_online
FROM broadcasts 
WHERE DATE(start_time) = '2018-01-01' AND (HOUR(start_time) = '0' OR 
HOUR(end_time) >= '0')
```

Is there a better way of querying the data I need? Perhaps by using **group by** somehow? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if i am following, but try something like this:

```
 select datepart(hh, getdate()) , count(*)
 from broadcasts
 where datepart(hh, starttime) <=datepart(hh, endtime)
 and cast(starttime as date)=cast(getdate() as date) and cast(endtime as date)=cast(getdate() as date)
 group by datepart(hh, getdate())
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `DATEPART()` function. What's wrong with `HOUR()` like in the question?

Comment: There's also no `GETDATE()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that returns all the hour numbers:

```
SELECT h.hour_num, COUNT(*) AS total_online
FROM (SELECT 0 AS hour_num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 ... UNION SELECT 23) AS h
JOIN broadcasts AS b ON HOUR(b.start_time) = h.hour_num OR HOUR(b.end_time) >= h.hour_num
WHERE DATE(b.start_time) = '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY h.hour_num
```